# roku error "The channel code provided is associated with a channel not available in your region."

Tags: roku

Can someone please tell me why I suddenly get this error

```
The channel code provided is associated with a channel not available in your region.
```

I have done nothing different, even the channels that have been uploaded last year suddenly show this error when using the add channel code.

I am in the USA and all the channels are allowed to play in the USA and no matter if I add all regions it gives that same error or it does not show up on the Roku home screen.

Has something changed? Non of these channels violate copyright or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer after a series of opening other accounts and on my existing account. This is also the case for when a Roku channel app does not show up on the home screen page after a channel has been added and a system update shows it being installed.

3 things can cause this error.

1. The obvious. You do not have the correct region selected for the app
   (not in my case).
2. The app must be published when using the vanity code, whether it be
   a public or non-certified channel(not in my case).
3. The app must be named exactly the same as when you package the
   installer and the random file name must not be changed that was
   given by the package installer. (this was what happened in my case).

I hope this helps as Roku written articles by support and their tech support is completely clueless.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to login to your roku account and check to ensure you have created a US account,  otherwise your box will be associated with the region in which you specified there.

Comment: Thank your for answer. Can you explain in more detail as I have never changed anything and I do see a US in the ssl green bar.

Comment: Upon further research it appears that the only way to switch this is to contact support,  When did this error begin?  where are you located?(State) does this occur on every channel or a specific few channels?

Comment: It just recently started to happen and almost on all channels. 8 out of 10.. I am in the USA, near Roku headquarters.